# Regex that always returns false

Tags: c#, regex

**Objective:**

Use regular expressions to only display the actual folder name of a path. For instance,

```
C:\Users\Harti\GitHub
```

should be reduced to

```
GitHub
```

There is supposed to be a further rule to prevent users from entering a drive as a folder.

---

**Issues:**

1. The `if` condition returns `False` and I can't figure out why.
2. The line with `Regex.Replace(...)` throws an ArgumentException telling me (roughly translated) that, while analyzing the sequence `^.+\([^\]+)$`, there "was an unfinished [] clause".

---

**My thoughts:**

1. Any editor of my choice marks "C:\" as a match for the specified expression.
2. The double backslash in the `[^\\]` may be treated as actually escaping the closing square bracket, therefore invalidating the regular expression. Using `@"..."` for the strings resulted in the same exception, however.

---

Can you please point me to whatever I may be missing? I'm completely new to VS and C#, so there may be anomalies I don't know about yet.

**Code:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string folderPath = "C:\\";
    string disallowedPattern = "^[A-Z]:\\$";

    if (Regex.IsMatch(folderPath, disallowedPattern))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You chose a drive! Not cool!");
    }
    else
    {
        string suggestedProjectName = Regex.Replace(folderPath, "^.+\\([^\\]+)$", "$1");
        Console.WriteLine(suggestedProjectName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make this easier, use string literals: `@"C:\"` and `@"^[A-Z]:\\$"`. Otherwise, you must change your Regex to `"^[A-Z]:\\\\$"` because you must escape the backslash once for the string, and another time for the Regex engine.

Comment: This is almost correct. I'd have to be using `@^[A-Z]:\\$`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you should write

```
string disallowedPattern = "^[A-Z]:\\\\$";
```

since the backslash must be escaped both in the regexp and in the C string literal.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using regular expressions to parse out path information, why not use [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: I didn't even know that existed! Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: However, it doesn't seem to provide a method for returning only the very last segment of the path string?

Comment: Did you look at [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Ah, it seems I misunderstood the method name and description. Works like a charm (has issues with trailing backslashes though)!